# Why does my latex code not print both glossaries?

Tags: latex, overleaf, glossaries

I tried to make multiple glossaries with \usepackage{glossary}.
I just can't find the mistake. You can finde the code example here:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
%Creat Glossary
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Define acronym glossary
\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{List of Acronyms}
% Define symbol glossary
\newglossary[sym]{symbol}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{ABC}{
    type=acronym,
    name={ABC},
    description={some description}}

\newglossaryentry{s_l}{
    type=symbol,
    name={\ensuremath{s_l}},
    description={some description}}

\newglossaryentry{s}{
    type=symbol,
    name={\ensuremath{s}},
    description={some description}}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
k_{A,eff}=\frac{\gls{s_l}-\gls{s}}{s}
\label{Eq:stress CRC}
\end{equation}

Where \gls{s} \gls{s_l}t.

this is a text \gls{ABC}

% Print the acronym glossary
\printglossary[type=acronym]
% Print the symbol glossary
\printglossary[type=symbol]

\end{document}
```

This is what i got (using Overleaf):

kA,ef f = sl − s
s (1)
Where s slt.
this is a text ABC

List of Acronyms
ABC some description. 1

This is makeindex, version 2.17 [TeX Live 2023] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning style
file ./output.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored). Scanning input file out-
put.sbl....done (4 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries....done (10 comparisons). Generating
output file output.sym....done (8 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in output.sym. Transcript
written in output.sym.

Comment: Found a solution:

\newglossary[slg]{symbol}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}

exchanged "sym" in the [] with "slg"